# Latex: Elsevier paper template, adds a horizental line that crosses introduction title when switching to two column

Tags: abstract

In Elsevier paper template, when I switched to two column style the horizontal line that comes after the abstract section in the beginning crosses my introduction title which is the section following it.

Here is the beginning code of latex for the paper:

```
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn,times,procedia]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\volume{137}
\firstpage{1}
\journalname{Applied Energy}
\jid{egypro}
\CopyrightLine{2016}{Published by Elsevier Ltd.}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title\tnoteref{label1}}

\author{sdfsdf}
\ead{sdfsdf}
\address{sdfsdf}
\dochead{}
\title{dfgdfg}
\author{sdf}
\ead{sdf}
\address{sdfsdf}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
gfh
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\vspace{5pt}
\section{Introduction}
Due to population growth, 
\end{document}
```

Even I tried to prevent it to happen by adding `\vspace`, but did not help.

Comment: Are you meant to use `twocolumn`?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I need to have two column structure

Comment: It is just that usually a journal class will impose that automatically if it is required.

Comment: Oh, OK. I see they tell you to do this ;).

Comment: Where can `ecrc.sty` be found? Can you reproduce without it? If so, remove it. If not, we need a link as it is not part of the standard `elsarticle` package and not part of TeX Live, for example.

Comment: Switching to `5p` works...